# upgrade mariadb 10.3.3 to 10.5.5, Please guide me the steps?

Tags: database, mariadb

I want to update MariaDB 10.3.n to 10.5.5.
In my investigation, I have found that I have to upgrade its version by version. for example version 1 to 2, 2 to 3, and so on.
Can I upgrade it directly from 10.3.n to 10.5.5 in windows and Linux?

Comment: And you think mariadb is related to oracle so that you can use oracle tag for this ? Kindly update this and use the correct tags.

Answer (score 1):

First time upgrading MariaDB after 20 years working with MS SQL Server.  What confused me most was I did not understand that when you uninstall the old version of MariaDB, all the database files are left in place and will be used by the new version.

I just did the upgrade on a server with multiple databases supporting multiple applications, and they all worked fine after the upgrade.  Here are the complete steps I followed. Note these are for Ubuntu and Debian.

```
-- BACKUP databases
mysqldump --all-databases | gzip > /mariadb-backup/all-database-backup.sql.gz
mysqldump hhc  | gzip > /mariadb-backup/hhc.sql.gz

mysqldump phpmyadmin  | gzip > /mariadb-backup/phpmyadmin.sql.gz



--- BACKUP Config and database files
cp -a /var/lib/mysql /mariadb-backup/
cp -a /etc/mysql/my.cnf  /mariadb-backup/
cp -a /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d  /mariadb-backup/
cp -a /etc/mysql/conf.d  /mariadb-backup/




---  Update MariaDB repository
-- Show which versions are available in repository
apt-cache show mariadb-server | grep Version


--  Download the bash script.  Run all below in one command

wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup

echo "b9e90cde27affc2a44f9fc60e302ccfcacf71f4ae02071f30d570e6048c28597 mariadb_repo_setup" \
    | sha256sum -c -

--  Make the script executable.
chmod +x mariadb_repo_setup

--  Run the script.
sudo ./mariadb_repo_setup --mariadb-server-version="mariadb-10.5"



--  Uninstall the old version of MariaDB.
 service mysql status
  service mysql stop
sudo apt-get remove mariadb-server



--  Install new version
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
 

-- Check the Version
 mariadb -V

 --  Start MariaDB and run mysql_upgrade
 service mariadb start


--  Start meriadb and check its version
service mariadb Start
mariadb -V
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/upgrading-between-major-mariadb-versions/) says

> You should be able to trivially upgrade **from ANY earlier MariaDB version to the latest one** (for example MariaDB 5.5.x to MariaDB 10.5.x), usually in a few seconds. (...)

> Upgrades are normally easy because:
>
> - All MariaDB table data files are backward compatible
> - The MariaDB connection protocol is backward compatible. You don't normally need to upgrade any of your old clients to be able to connect to a newer MariaDB version.
> - The MariaDB slave can be of any newer version than the master.

So, I'd say that your *investigation* kind of *failed*.

- Read the documentation
- **Backup** first!
- Then upgrade

Comment: i found this information https://mariadb.com/kb/en/upgrading-from-mariadb-55-to-mariadb-100/ on this link. which says Make any desired changes to configuration options in option files, such as my.cnf. This includes removing any options that are no longer supported.
Start MariaDB.
Run mysql_upgrade.
mysql_upgrade does two things:
Ensures that the system tables in the mysql database are fully compatible with the new version.
Does a very quick check of all tables and marks them as compatible with the new version of MariaDB

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58405954/how-to-upgrade-mariadb-from-a-sql-dump-file

Answer (score -1):

I upgraded MariaDB old version 10.3.n to new version 10.5.5. It is working fine, without any problem, error or crash.